# What is the meaning of the notation $]a,b[$?

Tags: notation

I've seen the notation $]a,b[$ in several questions on this site, but I am not familiar with it.  Can someone clue me in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notation $]a,b[$ means the open interval $(a,b)$ and it's the [Bourbaki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicolas_Bourbaki#Influence_on_mathematics_in_general) notation.

Comment: So give a reference to Bourbaki if you claim it to be Bourbaki notation.

Comment: Certainly Bourbaki invented many new notations but I'm not sure that they also invent the notation of open interval but  at least I'm sure that they adopt it in their books.

Comment: Reference(ish) for Bourbaki: http://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/142/564 (It's not really a reference since the answer over there just asserts it's due to Bourbaki.)

Comment: This is the notation I learned and use in France. I didn't realize that it was due to Bourbaki, but indeed that would explain why we use a different notation

Answer (score 5):

It is the open interval $(a,b) = \{x \in \mathbb{R}: a<x<b\}$.

Comment: Ah, thanks much. :)